# Read file content and place it on vars

Tags: php, curl

I would like to know how to read this file:

```
http://persosalas.enteratenorte.com/albums/xvtrejo/album.dat
```

And place some of the values in PHP vars

I know you have to use the file_get_contents command but onces I get it, I dont know how to put some of the contents on vars

The information in the file are like this ones:

```
O:5:"Album":5:{s:6:"fields";a:69:{s:5:"title";s:30:"Quinceañera de la Srita. Trejo";s:11:"description";s:38:"El 15 de junio en el Salon La Hacienda";s:7:"summary";s:0:"";s:8:"nextname";s:3:"abt";s:7:"bgcolor";s:0:"";s:9:"textcolor";s:0:"";s:9:"linkcolor";s:0:"";s:10:"background";s:0:"";s:4:"font";s:5:"arial";s:6:"border";s:1:"1";s:11:"bordercolor";s:5:"black";s...
```

Comment: how do you want to add information to vars? `I dont know how to put some of the contents on vars`?

Comment: [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) - as long as the Album class has already been included in your code

Comment: Im looking to get the title, descriptions and some of the data in vars so I can add them to a SQL process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this and after that unserialize it.

```
$var = file_get_contents('http://persosalas.enteratenorte.com/albums/xvtrejo/album.dat');
$un_var = unserialize($var); // it will convert it to array. Now you can access them and put in variable.
```

Comment: @Nadh added just now. :)

Comment: file_get_contents() already mention in the question! read it again

Comment: @Akam I knows. See edited answer. And it doesn't makes sense to downvote answer if it contains OP's code. :)

Comment: ok, see @Mark Baker's comment, I think your answer is nor adds anything, sorry for that I just want to help you to improve your answer

Comment: @Akam See the timings of answer and comment both are same. How can anyone read comment while typing answer, :)